# Automatically convert DateTime object in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Service with a .NET backend. I am using an `ApiController` that creates a `DateTime` object and returns it to a .NET client (specifically, a Windows Phone app).

When this `DateTime`, returned as part of an object, is returned to the client, the time is automatically converted to a different time. It appears that Azure assumes that the `DateTime` is in Utc format, and tries to convert it to a local time.

I do not want this to happen because the `DateTime` should be the same for everyone who uses the application and so converting to a local time is unwanted.

I have tried explicitly trying to make Azure not convert the date by trying something like this:

```
dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

However, this has no effect.

**How can I make sure that `DateTime` objects returned by Azure Mobile Services with a .NET backend are not converted when returned to a .NET client?**

Comment: Is the value being changed or is the local time zone being applied as part of displaying the value locally? Try datetime.utc.tostring() in a view to see which..

Comment: When the date is returned to the client as a string, the correct time is maintained. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes. So the default is to convert to the local time zone. You should be converting dates that you are saving / storing to UTC and datetime is working with windows as expected

Comment: I don't want it to be converted. Imagine you're calling a service in Azure that returns the time of a sports game as 7pm. You then want to show the 7pm time to everyone who uses the app and not convert it to local time. The date is not actually being stored in Azure. Why doesn't setting the DateTimeKind to local prevent this conversion from happening?

Comment: The only time that is common to everyone is UTC. 7pm in California is three hours later on the east coast in the US. The time is being displayed locally on the workstation after applying the time zone rules the datetime to utc test ( which worked correct? ) but the value of date time itself is not changing it's just being formatted differently.

Comment: I am familiar with time zones and how UTC works. For my app, the correct user experience is showing a time that is local to a venue. Therefore, I need the same time to be shown to all users because the time in the venue is always the same. How can I accomplish this behavior?

Comment: In the view use datetime.utc